# 'React/RCTBridge.h' file not found on Xcode Installing MS AppCenter in an ejected CRNA new project

Tags: react-native, expo, appdelegate, visual-studio-app-center, create-react-app

## Goal

Installing MS AppCenter in an ejected CRNA new project keeping Expokit

### Environment Description

- Mac: 10.14.3
- NPM: 6.4.1
- node-v10.15.2

### Summary of what I executed

I tried to follow the [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/react-native) and a brand new project so all is cleaned.

- Create a new project

`create-react-native-app delete`

- Eject from expo (keeping expo kit)

`expo eject`

- Then we build both `ios` and `android`

`cd ios && pod install`
`cd ../android && ./gradlew installDevKernelDebug`

- Then we install app center dependencies

`yarn add appcenter appcenter-analytics appcenter-crashes --exact`

- And finally react-native link

`react-native link`

And as you can see the error of NSURL *jsCodeLocation; always appear.

```sh
Could not find line "NSURL *jsCodeLocation;" in file AppDelegate.m.
        Update AppDelegate.m so that text is present, as we match on it and insert '  [AppCenterReactNative register];  // Initialize AppCenter ' after for AppCenter SDK integration.
```

- Because of that I can not build the app in Xcode, in Android everything looks ok.

### Tried solutions

- First Attempt to find solution: Add the App Center SDK modules

As is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/ios), I added `pod 'AppCenter'` to the `Podfile` and re-run a `pod install`, but still the same output after `react-native link`.

- Second Attempt to find the solution, update pod repo.

Basically just executing `pod repo update` on `ios` folder but still same problem.

#### Detailed log

```sh
✔ robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop  create-react-native-app delete

? Choose a template: expo-template-blank
✔ Please enter a few initial configuration values.
  Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/ · 100% completed
? Yarn v1.13.0 found. Use Yarn to install dependencies? Yes
Extracting project files...
Customizing project...
Initialized a git repository.
Installing dependencies...
yarn install v1.13.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "expo > expo-background-fetch@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "expo-task-manager-interface@~1.0.0".
warning "expo > expo-google-sign-in@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@^0.55.4".
warning "expo > expo-location@2.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "expo-task-manager-interface@~1.0.0".
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.0.0-alpha.6".
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@^0.44.1".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.49.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
warning "expo > expo-asset > url-loader@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators > @babel/plugin-syntax-decorators@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators > @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.3.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-literals@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@7.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.3.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator > @babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding > @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread > @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining > @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types > @babel/plugin-syntax-flow@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript > @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 13.86s.

Your project is ready at /Users/robertovazquezgonzalez/Desktop/delete

To get started, you can type:

  cd delete
  yarn start

 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop  cd delete
 ✘ robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete   master  expo eject
We didn't find any uses of the Expo SDK in your project, so you should be fine to eject to "Plain" React Native.
(This check isn't very sophisticated, though.)

Warning! Your git working tree is dirty.
It's recommended to commit all your changes before proceeding,
so you can revert the changes made by this command if necessary.

? How would you like to eject your app?
  Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/ ExpoKit
? What would you like your iOS bundle identifier to be? com.acme.delete
tar: Failed to set default locale
? What would you like your Android package name to be? com.acme.delete
tar: Failed to set default locale
warning "expo > expo-background-fetch@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "expo-task-manager-interface@~1.0.0".
warning "expo > expo-google-sign-in@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@^0.55.4".
warning "expo > expo-location@2.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "expo-task-manager-interface@~1.0.0".
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.0.0-alpha.6".
warning "expo > react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@^0.44.1".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.49.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
warning "expo > expo-asset > url-loader@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators > @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators > @babel/plugin-syntax-decorators@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.3.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-literals@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@7.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.3.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.3.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator > @babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread > @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding > @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining > @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types > @babel/plugin-syntax-flow@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript > @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
Ejected successfully!
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete   master  cd ios
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete/ios   master  open ./
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete/ios   master  pod install
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `EXAdsAdMob` from `../node_modules/expo-ads-admob/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXAppAuth` from `../node_modules/expo-app-auth/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXAppLoaderProvider` from `../node_modules/expo-app-loader-provider/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXBackgroundFetch` from `../node_modules/expo-background-fetch/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXBarCodeScanner` from `../node_modules/expo-barcode-scanner/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXBarCodeScannerInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-barcode-scanner-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXCamera` from `../node_modules/expo-camera/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXCameraInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-camera-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXConstants` from `../node_modules/expo-constants/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXConstantsInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-constants-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXContacts` from `../node_modules/expo-contacts/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXCore` from `../node_modules/expo-core/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXErrors` from `../node_modules/expo-errors/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXFaceDetectorInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-face-detector-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXFileSystem` from `../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXFileSystemInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-file-system-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXFont` from `../node_modules/expo-font/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXFontInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-font-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXGL` from `../node_modules/expo-gl/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXGL-CPP` from `../node_modules/expo-gl-cpp/cpp`
Fetching podspec for `EXGoogleSignIn` from `../node_modules/expo-google-sign-in/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXImageLoaderInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-image-loader-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXLocalAuthentication` from `../node_modules/expo-local-authentication/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXLocalization` from `../node_modules/expo-localization/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXLocation` from `../node_modules/expo-location/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXMediaLibrary` from `../node_modules/expo-media-library/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXPermissions` from `../node_modules/expo-permissions/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXPermissionsInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-permissions-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXPrint` from `../node_modules/expo-print/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXReactNativeAdapter` from `../node_modules/expo-react-native-adapter/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXSMS` from `../node_modules/expo-sms/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXSegment` from `../node_modules/expo-analytics-segment/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXSensors` from `../node_modules/expo-sensors/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXSensorsInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-sensors-interface/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXTaskManager` from `../node_modules/expo-task-manager/ios`
Fetching podspec for `EXTaskManagerInterface` from `../node_modules/expo-task-manager-interface/ios`
Pre-downloading: `ExpoKit` from `http://github.com/expo/expo.git`, tag `ios/2.10.2`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `React` from `../node_modules/react-native`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `yoga` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`
// ...
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 54 dependencies from the Podfile and 63 total pods installed.
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete/ios   master  cd ../android
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete/android   master  ./gradlew installDevKernelDebug
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~  cd ~/Desktop/delete
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete   master  yarn add appcenter appcenter-analytics appcenter-crashes --exact

yarn add v1.13.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 5 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ appcenter-analytics@1.12.2
└─ appcenter-crashes@1.12.2
info All dependencies
├─ appcenter-analytics@1.12.2
├─ appcenter-crashes@1.12.2
├─ appcenter-link-scripts@1.12.2
├─ rxjs@6.4.0
└─ tslib@1.9.3
✨  Done in 7.11s.
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete   master  react-native link
rnpm-install info Linking appcenter ios dependency
rnpm-install WARN ERRGROUP Group 'Libraries' does not exist in your Xcode project. We have created it automatically for you.
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module appcenter has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Linking appcenter android dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module appcenter has been successfully linked
Configuring AppCenter Analytics for Android
? What secret does your Android app use? [None] fc33836c-e18f-4b2f-961d-c6e606a576f9
App Secret for Android written to android/app/src/main/assets/appcenter-config.json
Configuring AppCenter for iOS
Adding AppCenter configuration file...
? What secret does your iOS app use? [None] 95019d20-4be9-4e05-90fc-0b0d7fc298c3
App Secret for iOS written to ios/delete-yeah/AppCenter-Config.plist
Patching file ios/delete-yeah/AppDelegate.m
Could not configure AppCenter for iOS. Error Reason -
        Could not find line "NSURL *jsCodeLocation;" in file AppDelegate.m.
        Update AppDelegate.m so that text is present, as we match on it and insert '  [AppCenterReactNative register];  // Initialize AppCenter ' after for AppCenter SDK integration.

Configuring AppCenter Analytics for iOS
Adding AppCenter configuration file...
iOS App Secret is already set in ios/delete-yeah/AppCenter-Config.plist
? For the iOS app, should user tracking be enabled automatically? Enable Automatically
Patching file ios/delete-yeah/AppDelegate.m
Could not configure AppCenter Analytics for iOS. Error Reason -
        Could not find line "NSURL *jsCodeLocation;" in file AppDelegate.m.
        Update AppDelegate.m so that text is present, as we match on it and insert '  [AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics registerWithInitiallyEnabled:true];  // Initialize AppCenter analytics' after for AppCenter SDK integration.

rnpm-install info Linking appcenter-crashes ios dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module appcenter-crashes has been successfully linked
rnpm-install info Linking appcenter-crashes android dependency
rnpm-install info Platform 'android' module appcenter-crashes has been successfully linked
Configuring AppCenter Crashes for Android
Android App Secret is already set in android/app/src/main/assets/appcenter-config.json
? For the Android app, should crashes be sent automatically or processed in JavaScript before b
eing sent? Automatically
Configuring AppCenter Crashes for iOS
Adding AppCenter configuration file...
iOS App Secret is already set in ios/delete-yeah/AppCenter-Config.plist
? For the iOS app, should crashes be sent automatically or processed in JavaScript before being
 sent? Automatically
Patching file ios/delete-yeah/AppDelegate.m
Could not configure AppCenter Crashes for iOS. Error Reason -
        Could not find line "NSURL *jsCodeLocation;" in file AppDelegate.m.
        Update AppDelegate.m so that text is present, as we match on it and insert '  [AppCenterReactNativeCrashes registerWithAutomaticProcessing];  // Initialize AppCenter crashes' after for AppCenter SDK integration.

 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete   master  open ./ios
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop/delete   master  cd ..
 robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop  npm install; npm run tesnpm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/robertovazquezgonzalez/Desktop/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/robertovazquezgonzalez/Desktop/package.json'
npm WARN Desktop No description
npm WARN Desktop No repository field.
npm WARN Desktop No README data
npm WARN Desktop No license field.

up to date in 0.761s
found 0 vulnerabilities

npm ERR! path /Users/robertovazquezgonzalez/Desktop/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/robertovazquezgonzalez/Desktop/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/robertovazquezgonzalez/.npm/_logs/2019-03-04T12_24_18_234Z-debug.log
 ✘ robertovazquezgonzalez@Robertos-MBP  ~/Desktop  create-react-native-app delete
```

### First Problem

I think it's a pretty straightforward problem someone should have experienced already, maybe I have to eject completely expo to have `AppCenter` working, but I thought it was possible to keep expo on the project and use AppCenter to manage all deployments.

### Now Problem with Xcode

I made huge progress, I was able to finish the installation of AppCenter with no problem by adding those extra steps to the https://learn.microsoft.com/
en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/react-native:

- Add `NSURL \*jsCodeLocation;` line to the `AppDelgate.m`
- Add this exact Pods to the ios/Podfile

```
  pod 'AppCenter', '~> 1.13.2'
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 1.13.2'
  pod 'AppCenter/Push', '~> 1.13.2'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 1.13.2'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 1.12.2'
```

- Run `cd ios/ && pod repo update; pod install`
- Then back to root and install dependencies for AppCenter 
  `cd ../ && npm install --save-exact appcenter appcenter-analytics appcenter-crashes appcenter-push`
- And finally being able to run link with no error:

`react-native link`

And now getting `'React/RCTBridge.h' file not found` on Xcode.

Comment: We are still with problems, now with xCode, I'm getting build failed, showing in the file:
`Pods>Development Pods>React>Core>Base>RCTAssert.h` has the problem `'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found` on line 10.

So I created a github repo with this info so it's easy to re-create: https://github.com/robertovg/rn-appcenter-expo

Comment: I don't think the issue is with AppCenter. You should open that issue with react-native. Did you solve it?

Comment: I have to say that I have tried a lot of solutions but that just helped me
  -  "pod install"